# displays float into Text View

Tags: android

I want to display a float into Text View

Comment: You want set a float value to textview right?

Comment: plz elaborate your question and senario

Comment: Yes I want to set a float value to textview

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this :

```
 float myfloatvariable=(float) 2.33333;
 String mytext=Float.toString(myfloatvariable);
 TextView.setText(mytext);
```

Comment: You can also use Double.toString(mydoubleVariable); if you have double variable type....

Answer (score 1):

Try this

- `myTextView.setText(Float.toString(floatVar));`
- `myTextView.setText(String.valueOf(floatVar));`
- `myTextView.setText(floatVar+"");`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you want something like

```
myText.setText = myFloat.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
///// for float value ////
Float flt_value = 1.134f;
txt_total.setText(String.format("%.02f",flt_value));

///// for double value ////
double dbl_value = 1.134;
txt_total.setText(String.format("%.2f",dbl_value));
```

Answer (score 0):

Something that I have used in my own experience.

```
aTextView.setText(Float.toString(yourFloat));
```